# Include JS file on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework

I was developing App in pure Cordova. And I decided to migrate to Ionic for having more resources. But I wanted to keep some things, I do not want to redo.

I have a JS file making a link from an API in PHP. I want to display the screen of this file in feed.html. I already added the JS file in src / index.html, how to continue?

My JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.get('http://test.com/api/app.php', function(data) {
$("#list").html(data);
});
});
```

File src/index.html:

```html
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

  <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
        .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
        .catch(err => console.error('Error', err));
    }
  </script>-->

  <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

My feed.html:

```html
<ion-header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/materialize.css">
  

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Feed</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <div id="list"></div>

</ion-content>
```